# ios - QLPreviewController can't present properly

Tags: ios, objective-c

I having an issue presenting QLPreviewController:

```
QLPreviewController *previewController = [[QLPreviewController alloc] init];
previewController.dataSource = self;
previewController.delegate = self;
```

When I try to present it to a UIViewController or navigation controller, I get these errors:

> Unbalanced calls to begin/end appearance transitions for <QLRemotePreviewContentController: 0x17a67400>.

followed by:

> Communications error: <OS_xpc_error:  { count = 1, contents =
>       "XPCErrorDescription" => <string: 0x3595f854> { length = 22, contents = "Connection interrupted" }
>   }>

Which sometimes crashes the app. Here is the code for those:

```
[[self navigationController] presentViewController:previewController animated:YES completion:nil];
[self presentViewController:previewController animated:YES completion:nil];
```

Now when I push it to navigation controller like so:

```
[[self navigationController] pushViewController:previewController animated:YES];
```

I don't get any errors, but the thumbnail bar is missing. How is this happening?

What I am trying to do is display the QLPreviewController without any errors and have the thumbnail bar.

Comment: Why are you calling `presentViewController` twice?

Comment: No, those are just items i have tried, usually one of them is commented out